# Max of date for each customer with date slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset like below

[image]

I have a date slicer aswell

My requirement is to get the max of date for every name when slicer is selected aswell.

I was able to get the max of date without slicer but when slicer is selected my logic is not working

```
CALCULATE(MAX(Orders[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(Orders,Orders[Name]))
```

but this logic not working when date slicer is active.

I need as below

```
a  10/1/2023
b  8/28/2023
c  6/15/2023
```

if slicer is selected for **9/30/2023**, I need as below

```
a  9/1/2023
b  8/28/2023
c  6/15/2023
```

Any help is appretiated

Comment: Is your slicer coming from a date table ?

Comment: Thanks for comment @AmiraBedhiafi, No its coming from same table date column

Comment: Can you provide more data?

Comment: You are going to have to use a separate table for the date slicer. Create a Date table and then add the relationship to the Date column. Table Tools > New Table, `Calendar = CALENDARAUTO()`

Comment: @SamNseir thanks for the suggestion, will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

By using `ALLEXCEPT(Orders,Orders[Name])` you are effectively removing the slicer/filter context on the table. Simply try:

```
Max Order Date = MAX(Orders[Date])
```

And in case you need it - you can also have:

```
Max Order Date = 
  var maxDate = LASTDATE(Orders[Date])
  var result = CALCULATE(MAX(Orders[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(Orders,Orders[Name]), Orders[Date] <= maxDate)
  RETURN result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately its not working as expected, I am not getting the required result when slicer is active